# In Javascript multiple onclick(); Collect Date and Single function

Tags: javascript, performance, onclick, dom-events

```js
function t1() {
        var show1 = document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML;
        window.alert(show1)
}

function t2() {
        var show2 = document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML;
        window.alert(show2)
}

function t3() {
        var show3 = document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML;
        window.alert(show3)
}
```

```html
<div>

<p id="p1">I am Headign 1</p>
<p id="p2">I am Headign 2</p>
<p id="p3">I am Headign 3</p>

</div>





<button onclick="t1();">Bt 1</button>
<button onclick="t2();">Bt 2</button>
<button onclick="t3();">Bt 3</button>
```

In this program, there are 3 functions are used for a run similar program. How to use only one function and grab all the information as I mentioned in this program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution

```
<script type = "test/javascript">
    function t(i) {
        let show = document.getElementById("p" + i).innerHTML;
        window.alert(show);
    }
</script>



<button onclick="t(1);">Bt 1</button>
<button onclick="t(2);">Bt 2</button>
<button onclick="t(3);">Bt 3</button>
```

Comment: i - is parameter of function t. On click you callc this function with parameter. 
In the function you use this parameter as part of id of element

Answer (score 0):

You can use event delegation to do that so you need no ids for the `<p>` elements, and pls don't write inline **JS** it has lot of disadvantages

```js
/* the onclick event can be delegated so you can have only one 
 * listener for the parent element */
document.querySelector("div").onclick = function(e) {
  // alert the innerHTML only if the element is a `<p>`
  e.target.nodeName === "P" && alert(e.target.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>I am Headign 1</p>
  <p>I am Headign 2</p>
  <p>I am Headign 3</p>
</div>
```